# Have any "blockages" ever been observed in the body's EM field?

Tags: medical-science, biophysics, electromagnetism

Crystal healing techniques speak of blockages in the body's electromagnetic field.
Electromagnetic fields can usually be measured and observed. So, it seems to me, if a body's electromagnetic field experiences some sort of anomaly, it would be observable.

Has this been researched? Have any of the blockages that crystal healing techniques speak of been observed?

Comment: Does the body even *have* an electromagnetic field?

Comment: Yes, of course it does.

Comment: But so does everything, in one way or another.

Comment: @Lagerbaer - I'm not sure that's true. An inert object that is not conducting electricity and has no polarity (e.g. a piece of copper) would not have an EM field.

Comment: Agreed, but everything "reacts" in one way or another with surrounding EM fields, since the polarizability should never be exactly zero.

Comment: An inert object that is not conducting electricity and has no polarity would still emit thermal radiation, which is made of up electromagnetic fields.

Answer (score 13):

Most of these claims don't describe EM energy, just some mysterious and non-measurable "energy" or chi. Supposedly, it can be felt by those that are sensitive to it, but no objective measurements can be taken of this so-called energy.

If you assume that such "energy" is hokum, then manipulation of it by any means is as well.

Comment: Is electormagnetic sensitivity a hoax? (http://www.aehf.com/articles/em_sensitive.html)

Comment: "Most of these claims don't describe EM energy." Yes, the body puts out an EM field. Yes, some people are more sensitive to it than others; however if you want to alter this field, you would do better to use electro-magnets than crystals. Does this have an effect on the body? here are of course studies that indicate that EM fields may have either a positive or negative effect on the bosy (generally the nervous system), but nothing conclusive yet. Here's a cool one http://j.mp/dOMu73.

Comment: "Yes, the body puts out an EM field. Yes, some people are more sensitive to it than others."  Sensitive to what?  Their own fields?  o_O

Comment: I've heard of people that can sense magnetic fields put out by active wires, and even my sister can sense magnetic north. (I have NO sense of direction). I was just pointing out that while animals of all types generate ME fields, and while it is possible to be somewhat sensitive to this, it still does not describe chi, auras, life energy, mana, or whatever else you want to call some mysterious "energy" that has never been objectively measured.

Comment: Youre not answering the question regarding magnetic fields at all.  You're just changing the question to something you can argue adhoc without reference

Comment: @jjj the term "blockage" doesn't even make sense in terms of a biological electromagnetic field. There isn't electromagnetic energy flowing around the body in any case. It isn't like the circulatory system. Nerve cells fire off electrical signals. Muscles move. Metabolism creates heat. There might be a few other sources, but those are the biggies. I suppose you would see a weaker field in a person with a spinal injury near the injury, as those nerves would be unable to communicate across the break. That said, we are still not talking about what so-called "crystal healers" refer to.